# Cucumber Test - Can anyone solve my 'edit' Scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, edit

I'm new to cucumber testing and I am confused as to why this will not work. As you can see I am trying to test that the updated details of a location are shown after edit but I recieve the below error. Can anyone help me spot what is wrong?

error =

```
Then I should see the updated location details # features/step_definitions/location_steps.rb:71
  expected to find text "#<Location:0x007fac52ca98f0>" in "/Location/289" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/location_steps.rb:73:in `/^I\ should\ see\ the\ updated\ location\ details$/'
  features/location.feature:24:in `Then I should see the updated location details'
```

feature.rb =

```
Scenario: editing a location
 Given There is a location
 And I am on the location details page
 When I click on edit
 Then I should see edit location form
 When I edit location details
 And I click submit changes
 Then I should see the updated location details
```

steps.rb =

```
Given "There is a location" do
  @location = create(:location)
end

And "I am on the locations page" do
  visit locations_path
end

When "I click on edit" do
  click_link "edit"
end

Then "I should see edit location form" do
  visit edit_location_path(@location)
end

When "I edit location details" do
   @edited_location = build(:location)
end

 And "I click submit changes" do
   click_on "Submit Changes"
 end

 Then "I should see the updated location details" do
   visit location_path(@location)
   expect(location_path(@location)).to have_content(@edited_location)
 end
```

Comment: What is `@edited_location`? It looks like you are passing in a `Location` object rather than the `String`. I would guess you want to pass in some property of `@edited_location`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few errors here:

First of all this step `Then I should see edit location form` isn't needed. When you click on edit you will be taken somewhere so there is no need to go somewhere else immediately afterwards

**Then's should only look at things, they should never perform actions e.g. visit**

The step `When "I edit location details"` is also very wrong. Here I suspect you are doing something with factory girl. What you should be doing is interacting with your edit form using Capybara and changing a value e.g.

```
fill_in(postcode, with: 'M1 3MM')
```

**When's should only interact with the applications UI**

Your last `then` repeats the mistake of doing a visit. It should already be there, if it isn't your code doesn't work properly.

There is a load more stuff, but hopefully thats enough to get you started.

Finally a couple of tips:

1. Learn to use the debugger so you can stop in your steps and see where you are.
2. When writing a scenario run it through a browser so you can see whats happening.